issue in working of pdfmake in mobile front
i am trying to make use of pdfmake for my angular project, the pdfmake is used to generate the invoice of order in my project. I is working completely fine for the web section but not working for mobile section. Where if we click on invoice button in web section it redirect us to the different tab and invoice document comes, but for mobile when we click the blank white screen appears. i have recently upgrades my pdfmake to v0.1.72
